# HighChart highlight point

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using HighChart with Angular: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts.

I am trying to replicate the demo of [Synchronized Charts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts)

The code I have is pretty much the same from the demo, with minor changes.

TS:

```
highlight(e: any) {
      var chart: Chart,
          point,
          i,
          event;

      for (i = 0; i < this.list_redenredCharts.length; i = i + 1) {       
        chart = this.list_redenredCharts[i];
        // Find coordinates within the chart
        event = chart.ref.pointer.normalize(e);
        // Get the hovered point
        const points = this.list_redenredCharts[0].ref.hoverPoint;
        const serie = chart.ref.series[0] as any;

        point = serie.searchPoint(event, true);



        if (point) {
            point.highlight(e);
      }
    }
```

Difference here is that is that I have my list of charts inside `this.list_renderedCharts` and my event types are received in my html div.

The result is the same until I get to the highlight part of the code `point.highlight(e)` where I will get the following error on the console: `point.highlight is not a function`.

The Demo on site uses highchart version 7.0.x, while mine seems to be version 8. Does any one knows how to get the highlight of the point now?

Comment: *The Demo on site uses highchart version 7.0.x, while mine seems to be version 8* The lastest Highcharts version was the 7.2.x. The 8 is only about the angular wrapper that you are using. Did you try to use the [official wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular) ?

Answer (score 1):

`point.highlight` is not a default functionality. It is added to synchronized charts demo only, so you have to add it manually to your app.

Make a new file and add below code there (example sync-addition.js):

```
export const syncChartsInit = function(Highcharts) {
  /**
   * Override the reset function, we don't need to hide the tooltips and
   * crosshairs.
   */
  Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function() {
    return undefined;
  };

  /**
   * Highlight a point by showing tooltip, setting hover state and draw crosshair
   */
  Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function(event) {
    event = this.series.chart.pointer.normalize(event);
    this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
    this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip
    this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
  };
};
```

Inside the chart component import and initialize it:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as syncCharts from "./sync-addition";

syncCharts.syncChartsInit(Highcharts);
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/ry839k99om

Comment: Got it... I failed to understand that highlight was a customization. Thank you.
I noticed your example works if the chart has only 1 series and/or no multiple yAxis. If there are multiple series or multiple yAxis, the `this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this)` fails with the error
`TypeError: (a || []).forEach is not a function`.

Comment: Note the above is only occurs if the chart tooltip shared is set to `true`.

Comment: It will work fine, just remove this line: `this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip` from `Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight`. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-cvz5j